# What is the session_register php function used for?

Tags: php, mysql, session

Just like the title says, what is the function session_register( ) used for?

Comment: Do not use this function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php

> **`session_register()`** accepts a variable number of arguments, any of which can be either a string holding the name of a variable or an array consisting of variable names or other arrays. For each name, **`session_register()` registers the global variable with that name in the current session**.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't, you'd use `$_SESSION["foo"]` instead.

Comment: More to the point, HTTP is a stateless protocol, so sessions are used to associate data with a particular user, **across HTTP requests.** More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_session#Web_server_session_management

Comment: It was built for the early PHP4-era, when `register_globals` was used.  You **do not** want to use this now, as it requires global variables to function.

Comment: so basically session_register( "foo" ) is same as $_SESSION["foo"], and therefore session_register is not in use anymore, correct?

Comment: @user, no.  `session_register('foo')` ties the *global variable* `$foo` to `$_SESSION['foo']`.  This is a horrible, bad, awful, no good design that should not be used in modern code.

Comment: It's not officially depreciated yet, but I have a feeling it will be. It's best to use $_SESSION directly.

Comment: @BraedenP, it *is* deprecated as of 5.3.  Scroll down the manual page a bit.

Comment: session_register() is deprecated in PHP 5.3.x so don't use it. Instead you can use $_SESSION['foo']

Answer (score 2):

This function simply adds a variable to the superglobal $_SESSION array which is used for keeping data for the current session.

A cookie is created in the user's browser, and when the ID in that cookie matches the ID of a session that your server has set up, it sets the $_SESSION array to that matching the ID.

Then this function sets a global pointing to your element in the $_SESSION array.

*Note* In order to use this function, you'll need to first initialize a session using session_start().

Comment: Your description is dangerously misleading, as it excludes the details about the global variable tinkering.

Comment: Fixed, sorry again. Not with it tonight apparently. :(